# Is this a more effective way to optimize my networking model?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

To begin I will explain my networking model:

Networking in my game consists of pairing objects on the remote server and the client. To give a short description, say there are multiple characters in the server world that need to be synchronized with a client (i'll consider just one to simplify things)

Each time a character on the server-side is created, the server will instantiate a ServerRpgCharacter - this class wraps the RpgCharacter and registers observers etc to monitor the character and broadcast relevant mutations to the character. The server then requests a pair object for ServerRpgCharacter (that is, it requests the client to instantiate a pair for this object that will communicate with it.) The pair can be any class, but any messages dispatched by ServerRpgCharacter on the remote end will be received by its respective pair on the client end.

It gets a little more involved with multiple clients but it ends up working out nicely.

Anyway, I have been thinking of multiple ways to optimize this model. The way it works now is that when an object dispatches a message to its pair, it is queued up into a 'snapshot.' Whenever any paired entity dispatches a messages it is thrown into the same snapshot. The snapshot is then compressed and dispatched at intervals of 200ms.

The problem is that I am using the TCP/IP protocol to transmit these snapshot. I'm not sure exactly how the TCP protocol works, but I assume that if a snapshot's packet is dropped, the entire snapshot would have to be re-sent.

Thus I am wondering If it would be more optimal if I discarded TCP and instead implemented a custom layer overtop of UDP where instead of dispatching one whole snapshot for all messages sent by all pairs, I have it so that these individual pairs maintain their own packet ordering and buffering. This way, if a packet for pair A is dropped, pair B can ignore the fact that pair A had one if it's packets dropped.

I then need to consider that compressing this data is less efficient since less is being transmitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression with TCP is more efficient as you can compress using the context of the entire stream. You cant do that with UDP as you have to compress each packet individually.

The benefit of UDP is you can drop packets and not resend them because you assume a later packet will update the information quickly enough.

The interval needs to be shorter as 200 ms will be noticeable to users. 50 ms might be a better option.

instead of the normal listener pattern, you can use a spacial lookup. When an event occurs it is noticable to things on the same level and for a distance of X squares. This will save you have to maintain lots of lists as players and monsters move around.